# Retain relationship between x and y data values in R plots

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

I'm fairly new to R but I am trying to create line graphs that monitor growth of bacteria over the course of time. I can successfully do this but the resulting graph isn't to my satisfaction. This is because I'm not using evenly spaced time increments although R plots these increments equally. Here is some sample data to give you and idea of what I'm talking about.

```
x=c(.1,.5,.6,.7,.7)
plot(x,type="o",xaxt="n",xlab="Time (hours)",ylab="Growth")
axis(1,at=1:5,lab=c(0,24,72,96,120))
```

As you can see there are 48 hours between 24 and 72 but this is evenly distributed on the graph, is there anyway I can adjust the scale to more accurately display my data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always best in R to use data structures that exhibit the relationships between your data. Instead of defining growth and time as two separate vectors, use a data frame:

```
growth <- c(.1,.5,.6,.7,.7)
time <- c(0,24,72,96,120)

df <- data.frame(time,growth)

print(df)
   time growth
 1    0    0.1
 2   24    0.5
 3   72    0.6
 4   96    0.7
 5  120    0.7

plot(df, type="o")
```

Not sure if this produces the exact x-axis labels that you want, but you should be free to edit the graph now without changing the relationship between the growth and time variables.

Comment: Thank you Will, I appreciate the help this is exactly what I was trying to do. I need to add multiple lines to this same plot and I am using the line function do that unless you have any other recommendations. Thank you again I truly appreciate your help.

Comment: As you begin to use more complex plots, I would suggest looking into using `ggplot2` as your go-to graphics package. In my opinion, it's more intuitive than R's native graphics support, and it has a very large following among R users.

Answer (score 0):

```
x=data.frame(x=c(.1,.5,.6,.7,.7), y=c(0,24,72,96,120))

plot(x$y, x$x,type="o",xaxt="n",xlab="Time (hours)",ylab="Growth")
```

Comment: This doesn't produce x-axis ticks or tick labels.